# Using multiple ports to transfer data to single device

Tags: can, data

I have the datasheet of a camera which has various interfaces (computer buses) via which it can transfer data to other devices: I2C bus, CAN bus, RS-422 serial port. I know the camera can use different interfaces for different devices simultaneously.

My question is, can the camera use all the interfaces to transfer data to a single device, assuming this device also has a I2C bus, CAN bus, etc.? And if so, will the speed of data transfer be affected negatively (total speed not equal to sum of the maximum speeds of each bus?)

I guess the answer could be device-specific. If that is the case, could you please share the most common behavior of devices regarding using multiple ports?. Thanks in advance!

PD: [Data sheet of camera](https://gomspace.com/UserFiles/Subsystems/datasheet/gs-ds-nanocam-c1u-17.pdf) Page 10 for info on Data Interface

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Depending on the device you're making and whether or not you create a way to interface your device with this sensor, you may be limited to how you can interface with your device you want to make. You don't _have_ to use every single interface. You typically transfer data with one interface at a time. I don't think I've ever had a time where I had to talk to the I2C bus and a CAN bus at the same time.

Comment: Hmm, what about transferring data from the camera to a CPU which also has a I2C bus and a CAN bus? Would using both buses at the same time increase the speed of data transfer compared to using only one?

Answer (score 1):

That datasheet does say " It is possible to enable multiple interfaces simultaneously".

So I am going to guess that yes, you can use multiple protocols at once. But most likely, each command is executed using one link only.

For example, if you want higher transfer speed, then you can not transfer half of the frame over serial and other half over RS422. But you may be able to command "send frame 1" on serial link, and "send frame 2" on RS422 -- effectively doubling the throughput.

(note: this is all guesses. I never used this particular camera model)